# Cannot read property 'createStyleSheet' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jss

I am using jss and I want to simply add a global css to a page.

My code:

```js
import jss from 'jss'
import jssGlobal from 'jss-global'

const styles = {
  '@global': {
    body: {
      margin: 0,
    }
  }
}

const sheet = jss.default
  .use(jssGlobal.default())
  .createStyleSheet(styles)
  .attach()

sheet.attach()
```

I get error:
Cannot read property 'createStyleSheet' of undefined

I following this example:
https://github.com/cssinjs/examples/blob/gh-pages/plugins/jss-global/app.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to my problem:

const styles = {
    '@global': globalStyles,
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  }

```
  jss.setup({
    plugins: [jssGlobal()],
  })
  const sheet = jss.createStyleSheet(styles).attach()
  sheet.attach()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing one pair of curly brackets. Try this:

```
const styles = {
  '@global': {
      body: {
      margin: 0,
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for fixing the typo, unfortunately does not resolve my issue `Cannot read property 'createStyleSheet' of undefined`